# Распарсить таблицу из ячейки pl sql

Tags: парсер, plsql

Подскажите, как распарсить таблицу из ячейки?

На входе ячейка с текстом:

```
||продукт||цена||
|хлеб|5|
|банан|10|
|итого|15|
```

Вы выходе должно быть две строки и два столбца. Кол столбцов всегда 2, кол-во строк динамическое.

Comment: СУБД - какая? точно, с версией. И что такое "ячейка"? термин-то для Экселя, а не для СУБД.

Comment: Oracle developer pl sql . Ячейка это значит одна запись в одном столбце (содержит большой текст типа clob)

Comment: У вас в поле таблицы, с типом Clob, записан кусок csv (или что-то подобное, какая-то ascii-таблица)? :)

Comment: Формат строго указанный - требуемые фрагменты точно соответствуют шаблону ```{пробел}\|[^|]+\|\d+\|{пробел}```? тогда рекурсивно [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://docs.oracle.com/database/121/SQLRF/functions164.htm#SQLRF06303) с удалением найденного фрагмента.

Comment: @gil9red ага( даже не знаю в какую сторону копать… из идей только регуляркой , но не могу понять как разбить одну строку на несколько.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> CREATE TABLE test (value VARCHAR(255))
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO test VALUES ('||продукт||цена|| |хлеб|5| |банан|10| |итого|15|');
> ```

> ```
> WITH
> cte (fragment, value) AS (
>     SELECT TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, ' \|[^|]+\|\d+\| ')),
>            REPLACE(value, TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, ' \|[^|]+\|\d+\| ')), '')
>     FROM test
>     UNION ALL
>     SELECT TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, ' \|[^|]+\|\d+\| ')),
>            REPLACE(value, TRIM(REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, ' \|[^|]+\|\d+\| ')), '')
>     FROM cte
>     WHERE REGEXP_SUBSTR(value, ' \|[^|]+\|\d+\| ') IS NOT NULL
> )
> SELECT REGEXP_REPLACE(fragment, '\|([^|]+)\|\d+\|', '\1') product,
>        REGEXP_REPLACE(fragment, '\|[^|]+\|(\d+)\|', '\1') price
> FROM cte
> ```
>
> | PRODUCT | PRICE |
> | --- | --- |
> | хлеб | 5 |
> | банан | 10 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=a689fd98380a5e9c8dc7d704cbc93cee)*

Comment: Спасибо большое) То что нужно